# GridView disappears when using Control Parameters for filtering

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView called gvPerson. Ive also created a TextBox and Button for searching through the GridView. The user can search for Personnel using ID, Name, Postion, and PD Number of the person they are looking for. I've gone through the SQLDataSource Tasks wizard to add ControlParameters. Every time I run the application, I can see the Search textbox but the GridView does not appear. It would only appear if I would type in a Name in the Search box. Also, when I add more Control Parameters for the other search requirments such as ID, Position, and PD number, the Search function no longer works Here's what I have so far:

---

```
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecurityDBConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Personnel] WHERE (([Status] = @Status) AND ([EmpName] LIKE '%' + @EmpName + '%'))">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Status" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="EmpName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work by using FilterParameters and adding ControlParameters to my SqlDataSource. I did not add the two using the wizard because the GridView would disappear.